# Использование матрицы символьных переменных в python

Tags: python, numpy, матрицы, sympy

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать использование символьной матрицы (состоящей из символьных переменных)?

Хочу использовать матрицу, например W

```
    | w[0,0] w[0,1] w[0,2] |
W = | w[1,0] w[1,1] w[1,2] |
    | w[2,0] w[2,1] w[2,2] |
```

элементы которой - символьные переменные, которые в дальнейшем можно определить
w[0,0] = 9 и вывод (print(W)) после такого определения будет такой:

```
    |    9   w[0,1] w[0,2] |
W = | w[1,0] w[1,1] w[1,2] |
    | w[2,0] w[2,1] w[2,2] |
```

делал так:

```
import sympy as sp

w = sp.symbols('w:3:3')
A = sp.Matrix(w)
S = A.reshape(3, 3)
```

но создание матрицы 3х3 не происходит

Comment: почему вы решили, что матрица не создается?

Comment: возможно она и создается, но обращаться к её элементам (в данном примере S[0] или S[0][0]) не получается. На выводе S[0] дает w00, а не строку w00, w01, w02

Comment: `S[0][0] = 9`, а затем `print(S[0,:])` ?

Comment: нет, так не работает: 
`S[0][0] = 9
TypeError: 'Symbol' object does not support item assignment
(w00, w01, w02, w10, w11, w12, w20, w21, w22)
<class 'sympy.matrices.dense.MutableDenseMatrix'>`